# Debugging Java2D in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, keyboard

I am making a Tic Tac Toe app using Java2D and KeyAdapter. I am using the Eclipse IDE. I set breakpoints, but Eclipse just seems to ignore them. I click Debug to debug the program, but it doesn't stop and I can't step through the code to see what it's doing. What should I do?

Comment: What versions of JDK and eclipse are you using?

Comment: JDK 1.7.0_60 and Eclipse Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)

Comment: Still having the same problem. How do we step through a program that draws stuff in a Canvas? My program is getting stuck and I want to see where it gets hung up.